# SQL LAG and Over function return error #1064

Tags: mysql, sql, lag, rownum

i am trying to use the SQL LAG function to get the compare population from previous year and current year, and then calculate growth. The code i am using keeps throwing error code #1064. i am using XAMPP server on a MAC.

The code i am using keeps throwing error code #1064. i am using XAMPP server on a MAC. i have city_code, period and numb for the population value field. The table is called population.

```
SELECT
    city_code,
    period,
    numb
    ,LAG(numb,1,0) 
    OVER(ORDER BY period) 
FROM population
```

I expect the output to display the new column with previous years current years population calculated and on the later stage the growth.

Comment: Presumably you are using an older version of MySQL that does not support window functions.

Comment: This will only work on mysql version 8.0 up

Comment: I'm guessing that `lag()` isn't available on your version of MySQL.

Comment: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

Answer (score 0):

please try this query. this is the replacement of row_number() that is only supported in mysql version 8.0. For mysql 5.7 below, using variables to generate the row_num()

```
set @pos = 0;
set @pos2 = 0;

select t1.*, ifnull(t2.numb, 0) from (
select @pos:=@pos+1 as pos, city_code, period, numb from population order by period asc) t1
left join 
    (select @pos2:=@pos2+1 as pos, numb from population order by period asc) t2 on t2.pos = t1.pos - 1
```